# android action bar input events

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to know if it's possible to detect more precise input events to the action bar than the navigation item selected.

I would like to be able to detect what a normal view would detect: click, longclick touch etc... for all items in the action bar : icon, menus etc... Is there an easy way ??

Answer (score 2):

You are welcome to use `android:actionLayout` or `android:actionViewClass` to have options menu items turned into whatever widgets you want, and you can then hook up whatever listeners you want to them.

You cannot hook up arbitrary listeners to other options menu items, whether they are action items or are in the spillover menu. Similarly, you cannot hook up arbitrary listeners to anything else in the action bar that are not widgets that you expressly declared, such as the icon, title, tabs, navigation spinner, etc.

If they are *your* widgets, you can set up listeners. If they are *not* your widgets, you cannot set up listeners.